# problem with sql command

Tags: sql

i have the following sql statement that doesn't seem to work :

> String a = "SELECT
>   c.comment_type, c.from_user_id, c.to_user_id, c.message
>   FROM comments c where COUNT(SELECT *
>   from friends where (
>   id_friend_1=c.from_user_id AND
>   id_friend_2='" + Session[0] + "') OR (
>   id_friend_1='"+Session[0]+"' AND
>   id_friend_2=c.from_user_id))>0 ";

i have a comment section and i need to display it only if that person who was commented it is my friend, so i look in my friends table that has 3 fields : ID , id_friend_1 and id_friend_2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your COUNT is not weel placed.

Try this :

```
SELECT c.comment_type, c.from_user_id, c.to_user_id, c.message 
FROM comments c 
WHERE 
(SELECT COUNT(*) from friends 
where (id_friend_1=c.from_user_id AND id_friend_2='" + Session[0] + "') 
OR ( id_friend_1='"+Session[0]+"' AND id_friend_2=c.from_user_id))>0
```